# Inline Modal Window question

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the great script Inline Modal Window from http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/inline-modal-window-w-css-and-jquery/.

When I use an form in the Window and click submit the window is closed. How can I prevent this?

Comment: how did you implement the submit button. On the linked page is nothing about a submit button. Can you please show me the peace of your code where the button is implemented, or how you handle its events

Comment: I included an regular html form:
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

Comment: good but how do you handle with it? what do you want to do after submit is clicked? where is the code it handles some action?

Comment: action="?" method="post"

Comment: @Luke I have an normal html form and when submitted it's check by php to see of all entry's are OK. When one of the entry's is not the form returns with warning. When everything is OK the data is send to the database. The window shouldn't close in the process.

Comment: em... are you using ajax? asynchronous postback, or is there just a <form> and just a <button> nothing else...?

Comment: @luke I have uploaded the file -> www.pws.nl/add_relatie.rar

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return false;" />
```

I dont know how to help you. You must be a little more specific.